# How to implement Bing Travel like UI in Metro style app

Tags: javascript, css, microsoft-metro, winjs

I'm looking for a way to make a layout similar to the Bing Travel app that comes standard with Windows 8. I'm developing the app using Javscript/CSS in Visual Studio 2012.

Here is a simple mock up:

[image: ui mockup]

The part that puzzles me is the first item that's being showed. Somehow, the first item is shown using the maximum vertical space, while all the next items are aligned in a gridlayout ListView..

I already have the gridlayout with the groupheader shown on the right. Is there a best practice for adding the first item? Should I add another parent css-grid with 2 columns (the 1stt with fixed and 2nd auto width) or can I somehow manipulate the listview to keep the layout simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved it, this is based on the VS 2012 GridLayout template. I did two things.

1) Created a (parent) grid layout with 2 columns with the correct
    overflow properties.

2) Disabled the overflow properties generated by the WinJS.UI.ListView control.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>groupedItemsPage</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/pages/groupedItems/groupedItems.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/data.js"></script>
    <script src="/pages/groupedItems/groupedItems.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #scrollContainer
        {
            height:100%;

            display:-ms-grid;
            -ms-grid-columns: 480px max-content;
            -ms-grid-rows: 1fr;

            overflow-x:scroll;
            overflow-y:hidden;

            -ms-overflow-style:scrollbar;
        }

        #col1
        {
            -ms-grid-column:1;
        }

        #col2
        {
            -ms-grid-column:2;
            -ms-overflow-style:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- templates -->

    <!-- The content that will be loaded and displayed. -->
    <div id="scrollContainer">
        <div id="col1">
            col1
        </div>
        <div id="col2" class="fragment groupeditemspage ">
            <!-- the code from the GridLayout example goes here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would go with adding a column to the element containing the first item and the ListView.  You could try and come up with a way to manipulate the ListView, but since you are group data it would be a pain, IMHO.  No reason to make things harder than they need to be.

Comment: This doens't work because the scrollable container is generated inside the listview; adding elements before the listview will just be placed outside the scrollable area.